# Opening new frame on button click

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

I've got three different GUI's that looks different and store variables in the class. I wan't to change to next frame when clicking on a specifik button. Also I wan't to be able to keep the values in the variables, example: Typing something in the textField stores the text as a string in a variable so the next GUI can use it. I'm not quiet sure how to do this therefore I'm asking here.

First class gui that should change to the next class gui on button click.

```
public class SearchTripList extends JPanel {
private JList list;
private DefaultListModel clientListElements;
// private static String[] colornames = { "black", "blue", "red", "white" };
// private static Color[] colors = { Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.RED,
// Color.WHITE };
private JTextField tfDest = new JTextField();
private int listRader = 0;
private ResultSet myRs;
private JPanel pnlCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
private JPanel pnlSouth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
private JPanel pnlNorth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));
private String dest;
private JLabel lvlVeckaAvgang = new JLabel("Vecka avgång");
private JLabel lblStad = new JLabel("Destination");
private JLabel lblTidAvgang = new JLabel("Tid avgång");
private JLabel lblAvgangFran = new JLabel ("Avgång från");
private String m = "                              ";
JButton btnSearch = new JButton("sök");
JButton btnDone = new JButton("Färdigställ");
private Controller controller;

public SearchTripList() throws SQLException {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    clientListElements = new DefaultListModel();
    list = new JList(clientListElements);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(listRader);
    pnlCenter.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    add(pnlCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(pnlSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pnlNorth.add(lvlVeckaAvgang);
    pnlNorth.add(lblStad);
    pnlNorth.add(lblTidAvgang);
    pnlNorth.add(lblAvgangFran);
    // pnlCenter.add(new JScrollPane(list));

    // list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    // public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
    // // setBackground(colors[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
    //
    // }
    // });
    pnlSouth.add(tfDest);
    pnlSouth.add(btnSearch);
    pnlSouth.add(btnDone);
    createListeners();

}

public void createListeners() {
    Listener list = new Listener();

    btnSearch.addActionListener(list);
    btnDone.addActionListener(list);
}

private class Listener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnSearch) {

            dest = tfDest.getText();
            try {
                connect();
                writeData();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else if (e.getSource()== btnDone){
```

//              controller.kvitto();
            }

```
    }

}

public void writeData() throws SQLException {
    String temp = null;
    while (myRs.next()) {
        listRader++;
        temp = myRs.getString("veckaAvgang") + m + myRs.getString("destination")+m+ myRs.getString("avgangTid")+m+myRs.getString("avgangFran");
        clientListElements.addElement(temp);
    }

}

public void connect() {
    try {
        // 1 Get a connection to database
        java.sql.PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/x", "a", "b");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Tur WHERE destination = ? ";
        // 2. Create a statement
        myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
        myStmt.setString(1, dest);
        // 3. Execute SQL query
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("Connect");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] a) throws SQLException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new SearchTripList());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Second class that should appear once clicked on a button on the first classs.

```
public class PersonInfo extends JPanel {

private JLabel lblForNamn = new JLabel("För namn");
private JLabel lblEfterNamn = new JLabel("Efter namn");
private JLabel lblAdress = new JLabel("Address");
private JLabel lblPersonNr = new JLabel("Person nummer (10 siffror)");
private JLabel lblTelefonNr = new JLabel("Telefon nummer");

private JTextField tfForNamn = new JTextField();
private JTextField tfEfterNamn = new JTextField();
private JTextField tfAdress = new JTextField();
private JTextField tfPersonNr = new JTextField();
private JTextField tfTelefonNr = new JTextField();
private JButton btnVidare = new JButton("Vidare");
private JButton btnAvbryt = new JButton("Avbryt");

private JFrame frame;

private String forNamn;
private String efterNamn;
private String adress;
private String prNr;
private long telefonNr = 0;

private Controller controller;
public PersonInfo() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
    setLayout(null);

    lblForNamn.setLocation(55, 15);
    lblForNamn.setSize(80, 50);
    add(lblForNamn);
    tfForNamn.setLocation(50, 50);
    tfForNamn.setSize(400, 50);
    add(tfForNamn);

    lblEfterNamn.setLocation(55, 100);
    lblEfterNamn.setSize(80, 50);
    add(lblEfterNamn);
    tfEfterNamn.setLocation(50, 135);
    tfEfterNamn.setSize(400, 50);
    add(tfEfterNamn);

    lblAdress.setLocation(55, 185);
    lblAdress.setSize(80, 50);
    add(lblAdress);
    tfAdress.setLocation(50, 220);
    tfAdress.setSize(400, 50);
    add(tfAdress);

    lblPersonNr.setLocation(55, 270);
    lblPersonNr.setSize(200, 50);
    add(lblPersonNr);
    tfPersonNr.setLocation(50, 305);
    tfPersonNr.setSize(400, 50);
    add(tfPersonNr);

    lblTelefonNr.setLocation(55, 355);
    lblTelefonNr.setSize(150, 50);
    add(lblTelefonNr);
    tfTelefonNr.setLocation(50, 390);
    tfTelefonNr.setSize(400, 50);
    add(tfTelefonNr);

    btnVidare.setLocation(275, 500);
    btnVidare.setSize(200, 50);
    add(btnVidare);

    btnAvbryt.setLocation(25, 500);
    btnAvbryt.setSize(200, 50);
    add(btnAvbryt);
    createListeners();
    this.controller = controller;
}

public void insertData() {
    try {
        // 1 Get a connection to database
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/x", "a", "b");
        // 2. Create a statement
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        // 3. Execute SQL query
        String sq1 = "insert into Resenar" + " (personNr, teleNr, adress, forNamn, efterNamn)" + "values(" + prNr
                + ", " + telefonNr + ", '" + adress + "', '" + forNamn + "', '" + efterNamn + "')";

        myStmt.executeUpdate(sq1);
        System.out.println("Insert complete");
        // Namn som primärnyckel fungerade inte så bra då det fanns fler
        // namn.

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void createListeners() {
    Listener list = new Listener();

    btnVidare.addActionListener(list);
}

private class Listener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnVidare) {
            forNamn = tfForNamn.getText();
            efterNamn = tfEfterNamn.getText();
            adress = tfAdress.getText();
            prNr = tfPersonNr.getText();
            telefonNr = Integer.parseInt(tfTelefonNr.getText());
            insertData();

        }else if(e.getSource()==btnAvbryt){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] a) {
    PersonInfo pi = new PersonInfo();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Person information");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new PersonInfo());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public String getForNamn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return forNamn;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do what you did in `main` of the second class? It looks like it would be the same code.

Comment: Don't quiet catch what you mean. Do you mean I should put  in
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.add(new SearchTripList());
  frame.pack();
  frame.setSize(400, 400);
  frame.setVisible(true);
Into the button actionlistener?

Comment: Yes, only with `new PersonInfo()` in there instead.

Comment: ah yea but this doesnt solve the variable problem?

Comment: This wouldnt work for 3 different jframes? class 1, 2 and 3. class 1 opens class 2 window, class 2 window opens class 3?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws SQLException {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   **frame.add(new SearchTripList(this));**
   frame.pack();
   frame.setSize(400, 400);
   frame.setVisible(true);
}


**private JFrame mainFrame;
public SearchTripList(JFrame mainFrame) throws SQLException {
    this.mainFrame = mainFrame;**
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    clientListElements = new DefaultListModel();
    list = new JList(clientListElements);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(listRader);
    pnlCenter.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    add(pnlCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(pnlSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pnlNorth.add(lvlVeckaAvgang);
    pnlNorth.add(lblStad);
    pnlNorth.add(lblTidAvgang);
    pnlNorth.add(lblAvgangFran);
    // pnlCenter.add(new JScrollPane(list));

    // list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    // public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
    // // setBackground(colors[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
    //
    // }
    // });
    pnlSouth.add(tfDest);
    pnlSouth.add(btnSearch);
    pnlSouth.add(btnDone);
    createListeners();

}

private class Listener implements ActionListener {
    **JFrame mainFrame;
    public Listener(JFrame mainFrame){
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }**
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnSearch) {

           dest = tfDest.getText();
           try {
               connect();
               writeData();
           } catch (SQLException e1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }

       }else if (e.getSource()== btnDone){
           **PersonInfo newPanel = new PersonInfo(some variables);
           this.mainFrame.add(newPanel);**
   }

}
```

Put a reference to your `frame` that you created in the main in the constructor of the first class then pass it to the action listener and when you create the new panel `PersonInfo` you can add it to the main frame.

Updated!

Comment: Sorry I'm new to programming, but what should i exactly put in add(newFrame); instead of the newFrame? I know should be the newFrame but what should it be in my case? Sorry If stupid question

Comment: I've updated the answer posted the fractions where you have to make changes.
Just as @4castle says in his comment put 'new PersonInfo()' in the action listener and you can put the variables in the constructor like 'new PersonInfo(variables)'

Comment: Don't seem to work for me, think Im just gonna use the simple method that 4castle suggested :). Or is that a bad habbit to do that way?

Comment: I'm suggesting the same as @4castle but only creating the new panel won't make it visible you have to add him to the JFrame that is currently opened.